# How to call custom uri using content provider kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

Basically what i want to call a SOS number using the android content provider from a smart watch. I have searched a lot but not able to find the correct path to implement this.
this is the uri:

```
content://[MY_URI]/table where cmd_key=SOS1
```

Here is what i have done:

```
   val cr = contentResolver
   cr.call(Uri.parse(APIURL.CONTENT_URL), "myFunction", "SOS1", null)
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The target SDK is 20, as the app is intended to be run on Kitkat only.